# Elasticsearch nGram search query containing blanks

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the following index:

```
{  
"settings":{  
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "blocks":{  
         "read_only_allow_delete":false,
         "read_only":false
      },
      "analysis":{  
         "filter":{  
            "autocomplete_filter":{  
               "type":"ngram",
               "min_gram":3,
               "max_gram":30
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{  
            "autocomplete":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase",
                  "autocomplete_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "movie":{  
         "properties":{  
            "title":{  
               "type":"text"
            },
            "actors":{  
               "type":"nested",
               "include_in_all":true,
               "properties":{  
                  "name":{  
                     "type":"text",
                     "analyzer":"autocomplete",
                     "search_analyzer": "standard"
                  },
                  "age":{  
                     "type":"long",
                     "index":"false"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And I have inserted the following data via _bulk endpoint:

```
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":1}}
{"title":"Ocean's 11", "actors":[{"name":"Brad Pitt","age":54}, {"name":"George Clooney","age":56}, {"name":"Julia Roberts","age":50}, {"name":"Andy Garcia","age":61}]}
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":2}}
{"title":"Usual suspects", "actors":[{"name":"Kevin Spacey","age":58}, {"name":"Benicio del Toro","age":50}]}
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":3}}
{"title":"Fight club", "actors":[{"name":"Brad Pitt","age":54}, {"name":"Edward Norton","age":48}, {"name":"Helena Bonham Carter","age":51}, {"name":"Jared Leto","age":46}]}
{"index":{"_index":"movies","_type":"movie","_id":24}
{"title":"Fight club", "actors":[{"name":"Brad Garrett","age":57}, {"name":"Ben Stiller","age":52}, {"name":"Robin Williams","age":63}]}
```

Now I want to search the index by actor name. For instance, when I search for *brad* I get all movies having an actor named brad, which is good.

But when I search for *rad p* I want only the movies with Brad Pitt, and not Brad Garrett, but I get Brad Garrett.
This is my search query :

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "nested":{  
         "path":"actors",
         "query":{  
            "match":{  
               "actors.name":{  
                  "query":"rad p",
                  "analyzer":"standard"
               }
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{  

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Endpoint I am calling is

> /movies/movie/_search?pretty

My question is, how to correctly implement the mentioned feature?

Thanks

BTW elasticsearch version is 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the `standard` tokenizer which will split the input into tokens based on whitespaces and punctuation, so `Brad Pitt` becomes `brad` and `pitt` and hence you will not have a token with `rad p` in it.

What you need to do is to change the tokenizer to (e.g.) `keyword` so that you consider the full input as one token which you can then apply ngram on.

Or easier, you can simply use the [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) and not the token filter

Comment: I've replaced my autocomplete_filter with an autocomplete_tokenizer and now it looks like this:      
"analysis":{  
         "tokenizer":{  
            "autocomplete_tokenizer":{  
               "type":"ngram",
               "min_gram":3,
               "max_gram":30
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{  
            "autocomplete":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"autocomplete_tokenizer",
               "filter":[  
                  "lowercase"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
All Brads are still there.

Comment: Did you delete your index, recreate it and reindexed your data ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. After adding nGram tokenizer I had to change my search query to:
`{
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"actors",
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "must":{
                  "match":{
                     "actors.name":{
                        "query":"rad p"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{
         }
      }
   }
}`

And now it works, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

As Val has said, you have to use the nGram tokenizer to do this, and I also had to change my search query to:

`{
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"searchable",
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "must":{
                  "match":{
                     "searchable.searchKeyword":{
                        "query":"%1$s"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{
         }
      }
   }
}`

My new index with the [nGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html):

`{

      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":0,
      "blocks":{

         "read_only_allow_delete":false,
         "read_only":false
      },
      "analysis":{

         "analyzer":{

            "autocomplete":{

               "tokenizer":"search_tokenizer",
               "filter":[

                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer":{

            "search_tokenizer":{

               "type":"ngram",
               "token_chars":[

                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "whitespace",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ],
               "min_gram":3,
               "max_gram":30
            }
         }
      }
}`